# Factor Group Lemma of Cayley Graph

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, cayley-graphs

Factor Group Lemma: Suppose that

1.$N$ is a cyclic, normal subgroup of group $G$.

2.$(s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_m)$ is a hamiltonian cycle in $Cay(G/N;S).

3.The product $s_1s_2\cdots s_m$ generates $N$.

Then $Cay(G;S)$ has a Hamiltonian cycle.

I can show the above theorem, but I cannot understand how we can conclude the following corollary.

Suppose that

1.$N$ is a cyclic, normal subgroup of $G$, such that |N| is a prime power.

2. $\langle s^{-1}t\rangle=N$ for some $s,t\in S\cup S^{-1}$.
3. There is a hamiltonian cycle in $Cay(G/N;S)$ that uses at least one edge labelled $s$.

Then there is a hamiltonian cycle in $Cay(G;S)$.

Comment: I am confused. You assumed in 2 that Cay$(G/N;S)$ has a Hamiltonian cycle, and then stated the same property as the conclusion of the lemma!

Comment: @DerekHolt sorry I edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_{m-1},s)$ be a Hamiltonian cycle in $\Gamma(G/N,S)$. If $N = \langle s_1s_2 \cdots s_{m-1}s \rangle$, we are done by the lemma, and otherwise $N = \langle (s_1s_2 \cdots s_{m-1}s)(s^{-1}t) \rangle = \langle (s_1s_2 \cdots s_{m-1}t \rangle$, so we can apply the lemma  to the Hamiltonian cycle $(s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_{m-1},t)$ of $\Gamma(G/N.S)$.

Comment: It is not clear for me. How do u use of order of $|N|$?

Comment: If $N$ is cyclic of prime power order with $g,h \in N$, $N = \langle g \rangle$, $N \ne \langle h \rangle$, then $N = \langle gh \rangle$. That would not be true if $|N|$ was not a prime power.

Comment: How do we use that N is a normal subgroup @DerekHolt ? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: The problem statement involves a hypothesis on $G/N$, but $G/N$ is only defined (as a group) when $N$ is a normal subgroup.